# How to pass Trigger type as a payload to “Method: projects.triggers.create " in cloud build

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-apis-explorer, google-cloud-build

I have written Python Script to create a Trigger in Google Cloud Build. So, I'm able to create it but, for Type it is setting to "None (no builds will be triggered)" and Filter "--"

***Python Script***

```
bashCommand = "gcloud auth print-access-token"
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()
if error:
    print(error)


headers = {
    'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+str(output)[2:-3],
    'Accept' : 'application/json',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
}


cloudbuild = {"build":
                {"source":
                    {"repoSource":
                        {"projectId":"[PROJECT_ID]",
                         "repoName":"[repoName]",
                         "branchName":".*"
                         }
                    }
                },
              "description":"API TRigger for all branch",
              "name":"[TRIGGER NAME]"
              }

data = json.dumps(cloudbuild)

response = requests.post('https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/triggers', headers=headers, data=data)
results_output = response.json()
pprint(results_output)
```

***payload***

```
{"build":
                {"source":
                    {"repoSource":
                        {"projectId":"[PROJECT_ID]",
                         "repoName":"[repoName]",
                         "branchName":".*"
                         }
                    }
                },
              "description":"API TRigger for all branch",
              "name":"[TRIGGER NAME]"
              }
```

I have to manually go to the Cloud Build trigger console and set it there.
Can anyone suggest me how to set ***TYPE*** and ***FILTER*** through the REST API?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the [feature](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/running-builds/create-manage-triggers) is still in [Beta](https://cloud.google.com/products/#product-launch-stages) and might change or have limited support. Add the [triggerTemplate](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.triggers#BuildTrigger.FIELDS.trigger_template) field and modify your payload accordingly.

For example if you want to build a trigger on your Google Cloud Platform's project default repository you could do the following changes to your script:

```
import subprocess
import json
import requests
bashCommand = "gcloud auth print-access-token"
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()
if error:
    print(error)
headers = {
    'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+str(output)[2:-3],
    'Accept' : 'application/json',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
}
cloudbuild = {
  "name": "[TRIGGER NAME]",
  "description": "[TRIGGER DESCRIPTION]",
  "triggerTemplate": {
    "projectId": "[PROJECT_ID]",
    "repoName": "gcr.io/[PROJECT_ID]/default",
    "branchName": ".*"
  },
  "build": {
    "source": {
      "repoSource": {
        "projectId": "[PROJECT_ID]",
        "repoName": "gcr.io/[PROJECT_ID]/default",
        "branchName": ".*"
      }
    }
  }
}
data = json.dumps(cloudbuild)
response = requests.post('https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/triggers', headers=headers, data=data)
results_output = response.json()
print(results_output)
```

Comment: ```"triggerTemplate": {
      "projectId": "[projectID]",
      "repoName": repoName,
      "branchName": ".*"
    }```

Comment: Added triggerTemplate things now its working perfectly fine